# vertical Centering sentences with fixed height

Tags: html, css

Used tranform to center the text inside an element.

- the sentence can be one line
- the sentence can be multiple lines
- if the sentence goes beyond 2 lines, overflow should be hidden.

In the case2 of multiple lines (overflow hidden is making the first line of  sentence to hide and how can I make it work with transform) -

Tried:

with transform value changes : failes when single line is available.
with table and table cell for centering: doesnt work in multiple lines.

required: Pure css solution ( no jquery/javascript)

```css
.parent {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
   <div class="parent">
          <div class="child">
            Helllllllloo I am here to see if
            I can fit this issues.
            I can fit this issues.
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="child">
            Helllllllloo I am here to see.
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it so in the first case you would only see "can fit this issues. I can fit this"?

Comment: No I want to fit two lines only on the fixed height div, when centering  it should be vertically aligned. Starting sentence shoyuld always be Helloo I am here to see.  when there is one line this should be vertically aligned to center. in two lines first sentece should not be cut

Comment: It maybe possible when using `calc` and `vh` or `vw`. what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @Vector all browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make use of `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/4ncdh507/

```
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  background-color: red;
}

.inner-div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

by using `line-height` (*the value of which should match the div height*) on the **parent** and then *resetting* in on the **child** element.

Also, set the **child** to `inline-block` and give it `vertical-align: middle`

`overflow: hidden` on the parent will trim off any unwanted text that extends below the first 2 lines or 40px defined above.

```css
.parent {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden; 
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 40px; /* should match your parent div height */
}

.child {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal; /* reset it here */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Helllllllloo I am here to see if I can fit this issues. I can fit this issues.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Helllllllloo I am here to see.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: height should be same for both, Shouldnt change ( it should be fixed height). Since height is fixed sentence when there is one line should be centered

Comment: @user2936008 Noted. I edited the answer. check again.

Comment: if padding is applied to parent element like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wycw9jyn/) additional lines get exposed. idk if that's a deal breaker for op @user2936008

Comment: @alex that's a very good point. Thank you. I can't fix that because padding shouldn't be there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

max-height to child div and add line-height to hide cut off part of a content.

```css
.parent {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
 overflow-y: hidden;  
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;

}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  max-height: 40px;
  line-height: 1.20;  /* hide cut off part of content all though you can adjust font size*/  
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
          <div class="child">
            Helllllllloo I am here to see if
           I am here to see
           I am here to see I am here to see
            I am here to see I am here to see
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="child">
            Helllllllloo I am here to see.
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

## Please describe your problem in better detail!

Without apt descriptions our solutions are almost no help.

With that being said, I suggest adding (from my interpretation),

`text-alignment: center;`

To your CSS. This allows the text to be centered (which I think you problem is).

Comment: Nop wrong. I gave problem, requirement and output I want to acheive still you are saying to describe ??